# jQuery show hide div in multiple checkbox using icheck plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, icheck

I design my checkbox with icheck plugin and worked with one and multiple checkbox(Check all) like this :

HTML :

```
<div>Using Check all function</div>
<div id="action" class="action-class" style="display:none">SHOW ME</div> 
<div id="selectCheckBox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="all" />Select All
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Check Box 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Check Box 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Check Box 3
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Check Box 4
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var checkAll = $('input.all');
    var checkboxes = $('input.check');

    $('input').iCheck();

    checkAll.on('ifChecked ifUnchecked', function(event) {        
        if (event.type == 'ifChecked') {
            checkboxes.iCheck('check');
        } else {
            checkboxes.iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    });

    checkboxes.on('ifChanged', function(event){
        if(checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == checkboxes.length) {
            checkAll.prop('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            checkAll.removeProp('checked');
        }
        checkAll.iCheck('update');
    });
});
```

I have `<div id="action" class="action-class" style="display:none">SHOW ME</div>` and `display:none`.

Now, I need to show `div` *if* checked any checkbox(all and one) input.

how do can I show this!?

DEMO [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N7uYR/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this that toggles the div based on whether or not any boxes are checked

```
function toggleDiv(){
    var showDiv=checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    $('#action').toggle(showDiv); /* if boolean argument, toggle will hide/show based on boolean */
}

checkboxes.on('ifChanged', function(event){
    if(checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == checkboxes.length) {
        checkAll.prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        checkAll.removeProp('checked');
    }
    checkAll.iCheck('update');
    toggleDiv();

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N7uYR/21/)**</kbd>

Comment: this not work true! please first click in check all you see `div`(true) than click check box 4 u hide `div` this not true because we have 3 checked box (1 - 2- 3).

Answer (score 0):

```
    checkboxes.on('ifChanged', function(event){
        if(checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == checkboxes.length) {
            checkAll.prop('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
             checkAll.removeProp('checked');
        }
        checkAll.iCheck('update');

        //Add this -----------------------------------
        if(checkboxes.filter(':checked').length > 0) {
           $("#action").show();
        }
        else{
           $("#action").hide();
        }
   });
```

Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7uYR/72/)